# Wordpress interfering with subdirectory php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installed in root. In one subdirectory, I have a collection of PHP scripts (a simple login system)

The same collection of scripts work on my other server (that has no wordpress in root) perfectly. They don't work on this server though. Please help!

Comment: Put them in a directory outside of wordpress...where the .htaccess of Wordpress cannot interfere...

Comment: Your question is equal to: "I have something and a Wordpress, and this doesn't work in some way." Please be more specific, this question can not be answered.

Comment: Actually, it's a common problem caused by wordpress .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an `.htaccess` file in your subfolder and put this inside:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

---

### As addition please note:

> If you are using Wordpress, be sure to protect yourself from hackers, and one step to secure your website and hosting from been hacked, is to NEVER have wordpress in the root, try create a subfolder for it

Comment: And the `.htaccess` goes in the subdirectory.

Comment: do you have any `htaccess` file in your root ? also check your subfolder, if yes, please put its content

Comment: I contacted my hosting service provider and they modified something in it to make it work. I have no idea what they did. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Good, I would prefer to know what they have done, but I guess I have an idea and I'm pretty sure its something a bit similar to the way using `htaccess`, many thanks for the accept :)